# Change of duration of stay

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration

My initial travel plan was to stay seven days in Germany, four days in Switzerland and five days in Italy.  I approached the German consulate and secured a visa.
Now due to issues I will be staying only one day in Germany and rest of trip stays the same. Will this create an issue when I try to enter Germany?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem if you are suspected of fraud. If you can document the issues that prompted your change of plans, you are unlikely to have a problem.

If you are very worried and if you have enough time, you can ask to have your visa revoked and apply for a visa from Italy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be an issue.

Your visa into Germany gets you into all Schengen countries. Once in the Shengen area, your visa will only be checked again once you leave Shengen area. Security checks do take place at airports (and randomly sometimes on trains or on the street), but only to confirm the person named in the passport and you are the same person. If your visa is in order, and you are not making problems, you will be fine. (About ten days ago I traveled from Hamburg Zurich Barcelona with a non-EU passport holder and we only got checked during boarding in Hamburg)

Business travelers have changes to their agenda regularly and even if you are not traveling for personal reasons, I don't see anyone being bothered.

Before someone points out that Switzerland is not Schengen, yes, I know - but it has special relationship for the free movement of people, not goods.

Best of luck!

Comment: Switzerland is “Schengen”, actually, it's the EU it's not part of.

Comment: Apart from that, two remarks: It's true that entering through Germany make things slightly easier but visa holders typically have to answer a few questions at the border. If you are asked where you want to go and for how long, you will therefore have to lie (a bad idea in general) or admit Germany is not your main destination (which may or may not be a problem but makes the lack of systematic border checks moot because the German border guards will evaluate your plans then and there, long before you set foot in Switzerland).

Comment: Secondly, how you look and behave *and the type of visa you have* play a great role. If you are smartly dressed, have a multiple-entry visa (they are intended specifically to offer that kind of flexibility) and many stamps showing you already went in and out of the area without violating the rules, you are exceedingly unlikely to have any problem. A young guy visiting for the first time could face a bit more scrutiny than your average businessman.